# Program linked against two versions of the same library?

Tags: dynamic-linking

I have two systems, both running Debian Jessie 8.4, and both have open-vm-tools installed. Files are identical on both sides. However, on one side the vmtoolsd links to an old libicu, althougth the file are identical, which gives me:

```
vmtoolsd: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.44: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here is the ldd output on the failing server:

```
root@asterisk:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu#   ldd /usr/bin/vmtoolsd
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffec070c000)
        libvmtools.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libvmtools.so.0 (0x00007fed5ba5e000)
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fed5b85a000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fed5b607000)
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fed5b405000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fed5b0f6000)
        libicui18n.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.52 (0x00007fed5ace4000)
        libicuuc.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.52 (0x00007fed5a966000)
        libicudata.so.52 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.52 (0x00007fed590f9000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fed58dee000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fed58aed000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fed588d7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fed586ba000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fed5830f000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fed58107000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fed57ed0000)
        libicui18n.so.44 => not found
        libicuuc.so.44 => not found
        libicudata.so.44 => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fed57ccc000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fed57ac4000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fed57856000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fed5bced000)
```

Only on this system it not just links to libicui18n.so.52 but ALSO links to libicui18n.so.44 ?!?! The other system doesn't have the strange dependency. I already reinstalled libicu52 and open-vm-tools. The file libicui18n.so.4 can not be found anywhere on the server.

What could be the reason for this behavour?

Comment: Please update question by appending output of `readelf -dW /usr/bin/vmtoolsd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're picking up `/usr/local/lib/libvmtools.so.0` which is presumably a remnant of a build done on Debian 6 (which had `libicu44`). If you rename that out of the way, `vmtoolsd` should find its libraries properly.